# How to integrate instamojo in Swift 3.2 and above

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3.2, instamojo

I have integrated instamojo in Xcode 8.2.1 ,swift 3 . It works fine, But when I came to run Xcode 9 swift 3.2, It is showing  "Module compiled with swift 3.2 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.2" like this . Can any one please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you update Swift code in Xcode 9?

Comment: yes I have updated

Answer (score 2):

get Instamojo letest version If you want Swift 3.2 build Instamojo refer to tag 1.0.10 in podfile

Comment: Hi... I have got latest version of instamojo from podfile that you refered, in Xcode 9.1 beta and I set swift language version as 3.2. But still I getting issue as "Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.1". Can you please help me to fix?